# need to match dates in excel and perform operation on column of this date?

Tags: excel

i need to write an excel sheet that takes input form the user as today's date and match this date in a specific table to subtract today's used quantity of goods from the stock we have . the screenshot below shows the sheet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhGkT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting something like this in the remaining apple quantity cell and extend that to the other ones (change the cell names of course):

```
=IF(TOP_DATE_CELL=TODAYS_DATE_CELL, (TODAYS_APPLES_USED_CELL - YESTERDAYS_APPLES_REMAINING_CELL), "")
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2